# Outline around span inside button in Firefox (screenshot included)

Tags: firefox, button, html, outline

I am having the following html structure in my page

```
<button class="badbutton"><span>Text</span></button>
```

The reason for this is so that I can make the text go a bit lower when the button is pressed, by means of relative positioning of the span when the button is active.

However, in Firefox I have an issue that I cannot solve. When the button is pressed, the span inside it gets a dotted outline, that persists even after the button is no longer pressed. I am attaching a link to an image depicting what I describe.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIL1R.png

I have tried everything I could think of in the css, to no avail.

```
a, a:active img, 
span, 
span:active,
span:focus, 
button, 
button:active span, 
button:focus span, 
button:focus, 
button:active {
    border: none;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: After a friend's proposal, I ditched the spans altogether and opted to increase the top padding of the button instead, when pressed. Alas, Firefox just keeps adding an outline around the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outline is a focus indicator.

It's not implemented with CSS borders or outlines on the button itself, since those have a quite different behavior.

You can get rid of it with

```
::-moz-focus-inner { 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```